# Matlab - Histogram edges and cut off

Tags: matlab, histogram

I'm trying to more or less replicate the following *p*-values density histogram, with different data: [image: [p-values histogram example]]

So I want to create a histogram with the bin ticks at the beginning/end of a bar. With 15 bars and the values ranging from 0 up to and including 1.

At the moment I'm using the `histc` command:

```
xint=1/15;
edges=(0:xint:1);
[n,bin]=histc(data,edges);
bar(edges,n,'histc');
tit='p-values histogram';
htitle=title(tit);
set(htitle,'fontname','Calibri')
xlabel('p-values');
ylabel('Frequency');
```

Which gives me:
[image: My code]

However, if the data is equal to 1, the current code plots a new bar after 1. I guess I need to include the edges (to get the same as the example), but I couldn't seem to find the right command?

Also how can I make the histogram cut off at x=1, like the example? Inserting the "lambda arrow" of the example at 0.6 is preferable (but optional).

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Would you please edit your question to include a copy of the plot your current code produces?

Comment: I have included the plot.

Comment: try [n,bin]=histc(data,[-inf,edges,inf])
But Matlab help recommends moving on to histcounts.
[n,bin]=histcounts(data,15) should work better.

Comment: I tried Including `inf` but that gave me the following error: `Error using barV6 (line 13) X must be same length as Y.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edits 3 and 4**: Since you're using Matlab R2013b, which doesn't have `histogram`, use the number-of-bins syntax of `hist` to plot:

```
[n, centers] = hist(data, 15)
```

Note that this returns *centers*, not *edges* of the bins.  For the arrow, you can use [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) if R2013b supports it.  Alternatively (a bit hackish):

```
line([0.6 0.6], [1750 1250])
plot(0.6, 1250, 'Marker, 'v')
text(0.6, 1750, '\lambda', 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'VerticalAlignment','bottom')
```

**Edit 2**: Try

```
xint=1/15;
edges_in=(0:xint:1);
histogram(data,edges_in);
```

to plot directly, rather than using `bar`.  [This post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91944-how-can-i-combine-the-options-histc-and-stack-in-a-bar-plot-in-matlab-7-4-r2007a#answer_101295) from MathWorks says that the `histc` option of `bar()` is deprecated.

---

Use `histcounts` instead of `histc`:

```
xint=1/15;
edges_in=(0:xint:1);
[n,edges_out]=histcounts(data,edges_in);    % <-- changed
size(n)
size(edges_in)
size(edges_out)
bar(edges_out(1:end-1),n,'histc');       % <-- changed - last bin edge shouldn't be included
tit='p-values histogram';
htitle=title(tit);
set(htitle,'fontname','Calibri')
xlabel('p-values');
ylabel('Frequency');
axis([0 1 0 2500]);   % <-- added - but leave it off for debugging
```

Per the [`histc` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html), "The last bin consists of the scalar value equal to last value in binranges."  So the last bin is just 1.0.  By contrast, with [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html), "The last bin also includes the right bin edge, so that it contains `X(i)` if `edges(end-1) ≤ X(i) ≤ edges(end)`."  That should do what you want.

I included an `axis` above to tighten up the plot, but leave that off for debugging so you can see if the last bar is still there.

**Edit** Per the [`histcounts` docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html), the returned vector has one fewer element than the edge vector.  If that's the case (per the `size` printouts in the edited code), it should be removed so `bar` doesn't plot that bar.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last bar is still there with using `histcounts` instead of `histc`. Meanwhile, `axis` indeed correctly tighten up the plot!

Comment: Glad the axis helped!  One more question: do you have any data values >1.0?  What is `length(data(data>1))`?

Comment: No, the data ranges from 0 up to and including 1.0 (nothing more than 1.0 or less than 0). `length(data(data>1))` is therefore 0.

Comment: The edited script produces unfortunately the same plot (with the bar after 1). The extra bar after 1, contains exactly all the values which are of value 1.0.

Comment: Indeed, that is weird. The code gave me this error 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.'

Comment: Thanks for all the efforts so far! Now I'm getting unfortunately the following error: `Error using barV6 (line 13) X must be same length as Y. Error in bar (line 47) h = barV6(cax, args{:});.` And `size(edges_out)` returns 0 - 0. (Of course you may get my upvote, however I don't have enough reputation yet to let the system show tem :( ) **Edit:** Your new code produces 16 bars and the xbins are centered: [See here](http://i.imgur.com/yYY1Khb.png). I guess the problem lies somewhere that the code plots 16 bars, while I need 15 bars.

Comment: What about `histogram(data,15)`?

Comment: On first sight it seems it does the trick: [See here](http://i.imgur.com/QBVXJ8B.png). It indeed plots 15 bars and when I use `[n bin]=hist(p_value_sr{6},15)` the first `bin` has to contain all values up to 0.0333 and `n` displays 3600 values. However, when I manual count all the values up to 0.0333 the "true" answer is 3292? Very weird... Also comparing this output plot with the [previous one](http://i.imgur.com/yYY1Khb.png) shows the error.

Comment: Matlab R2013b, moving this discussion to chat would be ideal (for the sake of clearness), but I need more reputation points.... ^^

Comment: Re. 3600 vs. 3292, I think it's probably OK.  The 3292 plot (yYY...png) had 16 bars instead of 15.  Going to fewer bars (QBV...png) means that the bins shift slightly so the bars are going to change height.  Also, you mentioned `hist` - did you mean `histogram`?  `hist` returns bin centers, not edges, as the second output, and behaves differently than `histogram` does.

Comment: Matlab (R2013b) doesn't know the function `histogram`? I thereby thought you meant `hist`.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realize that and don't have access to the R2013b docs :( .  Since `hist` returns centers, not edges, 0.0333 is the center.  Try counting all values `0<=x<1/15` - you should get 3600, of which (3600-3292) are between 0.0333 (0.5/15) and 1/15.

Comment: You are right, thanks! By any chance you have an idea to implement the "lambda arrow" at 0.6?

Comment: I'm now going to delete some of my previous comments so this isn't quite as overgrown :) .

Comment: Right after last my comment I found out I could simply add the arrow by using the Plot Tools (Insert tab > Arrow) provided by Matlab. But seems the code provided by you should do the trick as well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: how did you know to do `1:end-1` and not `2,end`? How did you choose which element of edges to eliminate?

Comment: @CharlieParker It was something in the histcount docs (see the very bottom of the answer), but what isn't jumping out at me right now.  I think it's because `end` is redundant when you have fixed-width bars, since the `end` is the right edge and `end-1` the left edge of the last bar.

Comment: @cxw sorry if this is a dum question but where exactly does it say this in the doc? Did you just infer it (rather than explicitly know from the doc) that using `end-1` was correct based on choosing the beginning of a bin rather than the end?

Comment: @CharlieParker I don't recall, but the comment in the docs that "The last bin also includes the right bin edge" does imply to me that `end` can be dropped without loss of information.  It may have just been empirical, though :) .